# Final Fantasy 7 Remake: What parts of the story are new and what was in the original?

Tags: final-fantasy-7, final-fantasy-7-remake

As far as I know, where the Remake currently ends is about 5-6 hours in the original game. But they blew that up to a good 20 hour game.

So I guess there are huge parts of the remake that did not happen in the original. So what parts of the game, in general, are added to the remake, and what was in the original?

Comment: The real question here is what is a retcon of the original and what is branching from the original.

Comment: Why was my comment on this question removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As comparing the original and remake to identify what was in both games would serve difficult, I am only including an overarching view of new or changed story/gameplay content that only exists in the remake.

The content below references [this guide](https://www.gamesradar.com/final-fantasy-7-remake-difference-changes/), as well as information that stems from my playthrough of the original FF7 many many years ago. These are likely not all of the changes, but it's a good start.

**Characters**

- The members of Avalanche - Jessie, Wedge, and Biggs - have much more screen time in the remake than the original. Chapter 4 consists of a lot of original content surrounding these members.

  Additionally

  > Jessie, Wedge, and Biggs all originally died in the Sector 7 collapse. At the end of the Remake, Biggs appears to have survived. Did Jessie and Wedge survive as well? That remains to be seen
- Chapter 4 introduces an original character Roche (SOLDIER 3rd Class)
- Chapter 3 introduces an original character, Chadley (Shinra research intern).
- Chapter 9 introduces original characters, Andrea Rhodea, Madam M, Chocobo Sam, and Leslie Kyle.
- The mysterious Whispers that follow Aerith around the entire game are brand new.
- Sephiroth makes his appearance much earlier than in the original

> In the final sequence of the game's conclusion, we get a small glimpse of Zack Fair. In the original game, Zack's cutscene is optional and found much later in the story. If you played the original or Crisis Core, Zack is known to have die in battle protecting Cloud, but we see a different take of these events and hints towards a possible survival.

**Side Content**

- Chadley introduces new "research" activities to obtain various types of materia, including summons
- Wall Market introduces new mini-games, such as dancing, pull-ups, and squatting
- Wall Market introduces Corneo's Colosseum, which consists of battle challenges and rewards
- Various towns include "odd-jobs"(or side quests)

Comment: So the TLDR is they reworked lots to be teasers for the part 2,and except that the more time is sidequest and fleshing out existing storylines. I really tought that it was more of the order that some chapters were straight tacked on the story, like the one in a haunted train station, that kinda felt disconnected from everything else.

Comment: That whole dungeon was original! It was just a lot shorter. As with everything else.

Comment: The squatting mini-game was in the original.